# Call from template with $_GET

Tags: php, html

So I'm trying to make up my own template for a site so it's easy to use and I'm trying to figure out how to include different paths.

Currently I have the below nested inside of my body with navbar.php

```
<? include 'content.php' ?>
```

What I've tried is

```
<? $_GET["path"];
include "$_GET" . ".php"; ?>
```

I want to change out the content.php so I have less static pages. I assume the above isn't very safe. What is an alternative to this?

Comment: You never should include a path comming from GET or POST which can be manipulated by the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it more secure, you can use an array for checking the to be includes pages:

```
<?php
    $validPages = array('content', 'home', ...);

    if(in_array($_GET['path'], $validPages)) {
        include($_GET['path'].".php");
    }
?>
```